# React Native How To Pass Props onChangeText

Tags: react-native

I want to pass id or key values onChangeText but it or i can only pass text value from Input TextField. How do i pass both id and text

```
 <Input 
  id={i} 
  key={i} 
  placeholder={`Question ${i}`} 
  onChangeText={(e) => this.editQuestion(e)}
 />
```

Comment: when i do this, all of the inputs have the latest id number. Let's say latest Input id is 10 then all of them are 10 on `editQuestion` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use function currying to do this.

First, set up your function inside the class to take the ID as a parameter and return a function that takes the event as a parameter:

```
editQuestion = id => e => {
  console.log(id);
  console.log(e);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
 <Input 
  id={i} 
  key={i} 
  placeholder={`Question ${i}`} 
  onChangeText={this.editQuestion(i)}
 />
```

HackerNoon have [a good article on this](https://hackernoon.com/curry-away-in-react-7c4ed110c65a) if you're interested in learning more.

Comment: it worked but why/how `editQuestion = id => e => ` can take text value here?

Comment: So this new curried editQuestion will return a function that only an event parameter which onChangeText will call with the text change event. The difference that currying makes is that essentially the function that onChangeText will get has an added context (the id you passed) that allows you to reuse the same editQuestion function for any input you need.